# Where can I find technical information on IE internal methods and objects?

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer, crash-dumps

I am an html coder, and I am [still](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444760/where-does-internet-explorer-8-store-its-crash-dumps) fighting a hard-to-reproduce crash in IE 8. Okay, I managed to get a crash dump out of it and I unpacked (decoded? deciphered?) it. Now I have a stack trace of what was happening before the crash and I want to find out what went wrong. It goes like this:

```
BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_NULL_POINTER_READ_WITH_SCRIPT
PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  NULL_POINTER_READ_WITH_SCRIPT
STACK_TEXT:  
01f898c0... mshtml!SRunPointer::SpanQualifier+0xd
01f898e8... mshtml!CLsClient::IterateOverCrossingSpansAndDoOperation+0x76
01f89948... mshtml!CLsClient::ModifyLineHeightForAlmostStandardsDocument+0x86
01f899b0... mshtml!CLsClient::CreateLine+0x212
01f899c0... mshtml!CLsClient::ReCreateLineForDisplay+0x67
01f89a74... mshtml!CTextDisplayBox::DrawClient+0x1e6
....
```

I don't know what does this mean. Unfortunately, Google is not of [much help](http://www.google.com/search?q=NULL_POINTER_READ_WITH_SCRIPT). And Yahoo. And Bing. And MSDN, too. That's actually pretty amazing, I feel like I am wandering through some sort of secret ninja interwebs.

Okay, my question is: how can I get more information about this? If MSIE crashes on my page saying "NULL_POINTER_READ_WITH_SCRIPT", what does it mean? How can I fix my html to stop this? I have zero experience in debugging windows applications, so I am completely lost. If Google fails, where to go? Who to ask? Please help.

Comment: you could do what everyone else does. fill a report and send it to microsoft. I doubt they would answer, but I don't think there's anything else you could do... except showing us your code so we can find what could cause that error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://connect.microsoft.com/ and submit a bug. Since it isn't in the bug list yet, this may be a not yet known issue.

Comment: I am staring at it for five minutes and still can't find how to do this. Where is the "Internet Explorer" category? Or "connection", whatever

Comment: In the "Connection Directory", search for "Internet Explorer 8", then apply to join. After this you should be able to submit bugs.

Comment: I tried that and have found only "Windows 7 and Internet Explorer 8 Security Baselines" and "Internet Explorer 8 Public Beta Feedback". These are obviously not what I am looking for.

Comment: "Internet Explorer 8 Public Beta Feedback" is the one used for feedback on IE8 after the release as far as I can tell...

Comment: From the IE feedback site: "Welcome to the Internet Explorer 8 Feedback program!  Internet Explorer 8 has now been released!" ... "We are looking for new IE8 bugs and bugs that have regressed (meaning the bug was previously fixed and now occurs in IE8 RTW).  Please continue to rate active bugs; see below for information regarding rating bugs."